# Delete pattern from a line

Tags: regex, sed

I have a file containing list of website and it's quoted in such order:

```
      "ProxyHost": "ie.review.visa.com",
      "ProxyHost": "ocasta.zendesk.com",
      "ProxyHost": "dev.zemanta.com",
      "ProxyHost": "bharian.api.useinsider.com",
      "ProxyHost": "optout.service.mycard.visa.com",
      "ProxyHost": "ir.newrelic.com",
      "ProxyHost": "metabase.yoast.com",
4:      "ProxyHost": "designdiscoveryya.gsd.harvard.edu",
18:      "ProxyHost": "pls.law.harvard.edu",
32:      "ProxyHost": "view.jquery.com",
46:      "ProxyHost": "www.rmf.harvard.edu",
60:      "ProxyHost": "execed.sph.harvard.edu",
74:      "ProxyHost": "note.microsoft.com",
102:      "ProxyHost": "librarylab.law.harvard.edu",
116:      "ProxyHost": "api.jquery.com",
130:      "ProxyHost": "pmsdn.
```

The target is: to Remove `any in-front` string until `: "` and if possible; also deletes `",` at the end of line. It might require double execution but let's focus on the main problem. The expected result would look something like this:

```
librarylab.law.harvard.edu
or
librarylab.law.harvard.edu",
```

Any remaining left-over `",` can be deleted easily using search-replace. Here's what i have tried:

```
sed "s/^*\:$//"
sed "s/^.*\:$//"
sed "/^.*#\://"
sed "s/^*\:$/d"
sed "s/^.*\:$/d"
sed -e "/^*/,s/\:/d"
and so-on...
```

All above give no changes into target file. I'm honestly confused; here's what i understand:

- `^*` or `^.*` : Mark Any first string.
- `\:$` or `#\:`
  : Mark end string `:`
- `/d` or `//` : to Delete

Any help would be cherished.

Comment: : "([a-z\.]*) =>https://regex101.com/r/qZvfsA/1

Comment: `awk -F '"' '{print $(NF-1)}' file`?

Comment: Thank You @MarkusMeyer for such direct regex and yet simple to grab website-name.

Comment: Also thanks for @Cyrus for awk variation, it's much simpler to understand. It's indeed work.

Comment: `sed 's/",$//; s/.*"//' file`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the last line with the unclosed `",` is a typo, then you might use

```
sed -E 's~^([0-9]+:)?[[:space:]]*"[^"]*":[[:space:]]*"([^"]+)",?$~\2~' file
```

In the replacement use capture group 2 denoted as `\2` as capture group 1 is used for the optional part at the beginning.

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `([0-9]+:)?` Optionally capture 1+ digits and `:` in group 1
- `[[:space:]]*` Match optional spaces
- `"[^"]*"` Match from `"....."`
- `:[[:space:]]*` Match `:` and optional spaces
- `"([^"]+)"` Match `"` then capture in group 2 all between the double quotes and match the ending double quote
- `,?` Match an optional comma
- `$` End of string

Output

```
ie.review.visa.com
ocasta.zendesk.com
dev.zemanta.com
bharian.api.useinsider.com
optout.service.mycard.visa.com
ir.newrelic.com
metabase.yoast.com
designdiscoveryya.gsd.harvard.edu
pls.law.harvard.edu
view.jquery.com
www.rmf.harvard.edu
execed.sph.harvard.edu
note.microsoft.com
librarylab.law.harvard.edu
api.jquery.com
pmsdn.
```

Comment: Thank you! I learn so much from this one. Definitely beautiful.

Comment: @Xav You are welcome, note that from 15 experience points you can upvote all answers that have been proven helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```bash
sed -E 's/^([0-9]+:)?[[:space:]]*"[^"]*":[[:space:]]*"([^"]*).*/\2/' file > newfile
```

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `([0-9]+:)?` - an optional sequence of one or more digits and then a `:` char
- `[[:space:]]*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `"` - a double quote
- `[^"]*` - zero or more chars other than `"`
- `":` - a `":` substring
- `[[:space:]]*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `"` - a `"` char
- `([^"]*)` - Group 2: any zero or more chars other than `"`
- `.*` - the rest of the line.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/lGl6VG):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
s='      "ProxyHost": "ie.review.visa.com",
      "ProxyHost": "ocasta.zendesk.com",
      "ProxyHost": "dev.zemanta.com",
      "ProxyHost": "bharian.api.useinsider.com",
      "ProxyHost": "optout.service.mycard.visa.com",
      "ProxyHost": "ir.newrelic.com",
      "ProxyHost": "metabase.yoast.com",
4:      "ProxyHost": "designdiscoveryya.gsd.harvard.edu",
18:      "ProxyHost": "pls.law.harvard.edu",
32:      "ProxyHost": "view.jquery.com",
46:      "ProxyHost": "www.rmf.harvard.edu",
60:      "ProxyHost": "execed.sph.harvard.edu",
74:      "ProxyHost": "note.microsoft.com",
102:      "ProxyHost": "librarylab.law.harvard.edu",
116:      "ProxyHost": "api.jquery.com",
130:      "ProxyHost": "pmsdn.'
sed -E 's/^([0-9]+:)?[[:space:]]*"[^"]*":[[:space:]]*"([^"]*).*/\2/' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
ie.review.visa.com
ocasta.zendesk.com
dev.zemanta.com
bharian.api.useinsider.com
optout.service.mycard.visa.com
ir.newrelic.com
metabase.yoast.com
designdiscoveryya.gsd.harvard.edu
pls.law.harvard.edu
view.jquery.com
www.rmf.harvard.edu
execed.sph.harvard.edu
note.microsoft.com
librarylab.law.harvard.edu
api.jquery.com
pmsdn.
```

Comment: I wish i can accept 2 answer. This is yet another beautiful variation of my expectation. I have not enough points to also upvote this, thank you so much @Wiktor for helping Regex community.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/.* "([^"]*).*/\1/' file
```

Use greed to remove everything upto and including a space followed by double quotes, capture the string which is not double quotes and remove the rest.

The essence of this solution is to find the last double quoted string in a line and throw away the rest.